# Zend Framework horizontal elements and vertical elements in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

When I display a form, it is just one vertical line of elements. The entire right side is unused. How can I have the form render elements vertically and horizontally, so they fit the entire page? I was thinking that I can throw the elements into display groups than use css to render the display groups floating left and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the viewScript Decorator to display forms exactly how you want. this [previous answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10349340/1145086).