# how to line up multiple (3) zend_form elements and their labels onto the same line using css

Tags: css, zend-framework

i've searched around and i've found 2 types of answers:
1. use decorators (there are several examples, but i don't want to go this way)
2. use css (i haven't been able to find one example, all i've managed to do is get a label and corresponding element onto the same line, but not to combine 3 separate label element combos onto one big line)

i'm no master of css so i could use some pointers here. even if it takes some javascript/jquery to help out, this is the route i want to go. thanx in advance

Comment: can you post basic code/CSS/JS here?

Comment: so far i have nothing noteworthy: 5 zend form elements with labels and 

label.inline {
  /*display: inline;*/
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

Comment: honestly the easiest solution to your problem would be the viewScript decorator. You can make your form anyway you want. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10349340/1145086 may help

Answer (score 2):

Use decorators, mate. The default decorators will put your form elements and labels in a dt-dd wraper. It would make more sense to use a different HTML instead, IMO. Try this:

```
// form decorators
$this->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'table')),
    'Form'
));

// element decorators
$element->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
     array('Errors'),
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'element')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
    array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
))
```

If you really must use CSS only, you could align the DD and DT items by making them inline:

```
form dd, form dt { display: inline; }
```

[EDIT]

Based on additional feedback, another possibility: you can also remove the dt-dd wrappers around certain elements using:

```
$element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
```

As for adding a class to certain elements, you can use this:

```
$element->setAttrib("class","foo");
```

But be aware that this will put the class in the input node itself, not on the wrapper, which you want to target in this particular case.

Comment: i don't want to simulate table in this case, so i'm looking for css solution. code you proposed helps, but it puts all elements on the same line, i have elements i don't want to be on that line, but above (before) and bellow (after) that line. can i add a class only to certain automatically reneded dd & dt elements using decorators, or remove them completely?

Comment: thanx for the help. i still hoave a problem however, ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper') removes those elements from my submit button, but not from other elements. is there something i need to pay attention to when calling this method?

Comment: @Ajant to limit which elements are effected by the css add an id or class. In Zend_Form you can pass a `->setAttrib('class' => 'myClassName')` or `->setAttribs(array('id'=>'myId'))` to the elements you want to isolate.

Comment: @RockyFord, not really, as this applies the class to the element itself, not to the DtDd wrapper :).