# Zend Form Element ViewScript does not work

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

In my form I have:

```
$uploads    = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('upload');
$options    = array('viewScript' => 'form/upload.phtml');
$decorators = array(array('ViewScript', $options));
$this->upload->setDecorators($decorators);
```

In /application/module/admin/view/scripts/form/upload.phtml I've put some random content.
The problem is that element is still Text Element.

I tried to use ah's solution from [Add some html to Zend Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566432/add-some-html-to-zend-forms) solution to put html in my form.
Against `<div id="wmd-button-bar" class="wmd-panel"></div>` I've got `<input type="hidden" name="dummy" />`

Notice: I'm using EasyBib_Form (https://github.com/easybib/EasyBib_Form_Decorator)

How to fix problem that element is not replaced by viewscript?

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How to fix problem that element is not replaced by viewscript

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the viewScript decorator. It doesn't change the nature of the elements it just provides more flexibility in how they are displayed. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349340/how-to-print-a-group-display-individually-from-its-content/10349705#10349705